# Find the shortest distance from the origin to the hyperbola $x^2+8xy+7y^2=225$

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the shortest distance from the origin to the hyperbola $x^2+8xy+7y^2=225$

i know that
$$d(x_0, x) = \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}$$

I also found this formula in my notes
$$ d(x_0,p) = \frac{|ax_0+by_0+cz_{0}-c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

I just haven't seen it been applied in class so i'm a bit confused.

This was in a week we were learning about Lagrange Multipliers and we don't seem to be given a constraint.

Comment: Distance to origin $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Constraint: your hyperbola's formula.

Comment: Contestant equals $x^2+8xy+7y^2-225=0$

Comment: $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\lambda(x^2+8xy+7y^2-225)$ and find the partial derivatives?

Comment: much better to use the squared distance, $x^2 + y^2.$ The $(x,y)$ location(s) where that is smallest is(are) also the places where the distance from the origin is smallest.

Comment: Hey guys i got a bit further could you see what i did?

Answer (score 4):

let $P(rcost,rsint)$ be a Point on Hyperbola. so its distance from $(0,0)$ is $r$, so we need to find Minimum value of $r$. Since $P$ lies on Hyperbola

$$r^2cos^2t+8r^2sintcost+7r^2sin^2t=225$$ $\implies$

$$r^2=\frac{450}{8sin2t-6cos2t+8}$$

Now max value of $$8sin2t-6cos2t+8$$ is $$\sqrt{8^2+6^2}+8=18$$

hence Min value of $r^2$ is $\frac{450}{18}=25$

So shortest distance is $5$

Comment: Hi Ekaveera thanks a lot, but i think i'm suppose to use Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 1):

Using Lagrange Multipliers we get two equations 
$$ (\lambda-1)x+4\lambda y=0-----(i)$$
$$4\lambda x+(7\lambda -1 )y=0-----(ii).$$
Since $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$  (does not satify given hyperbola), solving for $\lambda$,
$ \begin{vmatrix}
 (\lambda-1)& 4\lambda\\
4\lambda& (7\lambda-1)
 \end{vmatrix}$ =  $0$.
Solving above equation we get $\lambda=\frac{1}{9}, -1$.

Case (i): If $\lambda=-1$, substituting in $(i)$   gives $x=-2y$. Substituting in hyperbola we get $-5y^2=225$ which has no real solution.

Case (ii): If $\lambda=\frac{1}{9}$, substituting in $(i)$ gives $y=2x$. Substituting in hyperbola we get $45x^2=225$. So that $x^2=5$ and since $y^2=4x^2$ we get $y^2=20$.
Hence $x^2+y^2=25$. Thus required shortest distance is 5.

Answer (score 0):

taking $d(x+y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$$f(x,y) = x^2+y^2 +\lambda(x^2+8xy+7y^2-225)$$
$$f_x = 2x+2\lambda x + 8\lambda y =0$$
$$f_y=2y+8\lambda x + 14 \lambda y = 0$$

So i gotta solve the tree equations 
$$x^2+8xy+7y^2-225=0
$$

$$f_x = 2x+2\lambda x + 8\lambda y =0$$
$$f_y=2y+8\lambda x + 14 \lambda y = 0$$

So i need to equate for x and y by eliminating $\lambda$
i said $$x = \frac{-\lambda y}{2+2 \lambda }$$

$$y = \frac{-\lambda x}{2+14 \lambda }$$

From $f_x$ and $f_y$
 $$\lambda = \frac{-2x}{2x+8y}$$ 
 $$ \lambda = \frac{-2y}{8x+14y}$$

So solve...
$$ \frac{-2x}{2x+8y} = \ \frac{-2y}{8x+14y}$$
$$0=8y^2-8x^2-12yx$$

the remaining $\lambda x$ really complicates things

Answer (score 0):

To minimise the distance, the gradient at that point must be tangent to the circle centred at the origin (*):

$$2x + 8 \left(y + x \frac{dy}{dx} \right) + 14y \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
$$\implies (8x + 14y) \frac{dy}{dx} = -(2x+8y)$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{y}{x} = -1 \implies -\frac{x+4y}{4x+7y} \frac{y}{x} = -1  \tag{*}$$
$$\implies xy + 4y^2 = 4x^2 + 7xy$$
$$\implies 2(2x^2 + 3xy - 2y^2) = 0 \implies (2x - y)(x + 2y) = 0 \implies y = 2x,-\frac{x}{2}$$

and factorising the condition, $\left(x+y\right)\left(x+7y\right)=225$, thus $(3x)(15x) = 225 \Rightarrow x = ±\sqrt{5}$, $y = ±2 \sqrt{5}$, or $\left(\frac{1}{2} x\right)\left(-\frac{5}{2} x \right) =225$ which is impossible since the LHS is always not positive.

Hence the minimum distance is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{5 + 4 \cdot 5} = \boxed{5}$.